# How to pass all parent Props to all nested route children which uses {this.props.children}

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to pass all parent props to Children routes in nested routes

```
<NestedRoute path="/Resident" component={Resident} >
    <SubRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <SubRoute path="/policies/index" component={Policies}/>
    <SubRoute path="/pages/create-account" component={CreateAccount} />
    <SubRoute path="/pages/empty-page" component={EmptyPage} />
    <SubRoute path="/pages/under-maintenance" component={UnderMaintenance} />
    <SubRoute path="/pages/error-page" component={ErrorPage} />
</NestedRoute>
```

i am displaying this routes using `{this.props.children}`. I want to programatically navigate between pages in nested route using `this.props.history.push` 
i am getting error push of undefined. so i want to pass all parent props. but i don't know how.

I have tried

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child => React.cloneElement(child, this.props)))
```

it didn't work. my final goal to navigate programmatically from nested route.

Comment: where are you trying to navigate, some more context about NestedRoute component will help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `component` on `Route`,if you use `render` to for component rendering,you can achieve it in this way.

```
<Route path = "/dashboard" render = {
    (props) => (<Dashboard {...props}/>)
} />

<Route path = "/policies/index" render = {
(props) => (<Policies {...props}/>)
} />
```